# How to loop "refresh page" in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium to extract tables from Excalibur. When you upload a file into it you have to refresh the page until the page redirectioned to workspace. Shows:

```
<div class="container"> == $0 empty
```

Then when you refresh shows:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row pb-4">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="row">
```

I used "time.sleep()" but depending of the file and pages the time to wait increase and sometimes I get it error. Then I tried with:

```
`while True:
    if driver.find_element_by _linked_text('Workspace'):
        break
    else:
        driver.refresh()`
```

Only is freezed and the page is not refreshed

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to add a refresh cool down like so:

```
while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by _linked_text('Workspace'):
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.implicitly_wait(2)
        driver.refresh()
```

Without this Selenium will constantly try and refresh the page, so you'll kill your browser by sending a never-ending stream of requests that it cannot deal with.

Comment: For me that is a good and simple solution for non dynamic more static elements which are not contained by the dom until refresh.
But I have to say that the example code didn't worked for me because I got an NoSuchElementException. So what I did, inside the loop, was kind of:
`try: if  driver.find_element_by _linked_text('Workspace'): break except NoSuchElementException: driver.implicitly_wait(2) driver.refresh()`

Comment: Fair enough! I updated the code to account for the exception

Answer (score 2):

If the page automatically redirects you to where you expect this element, then I would recommend using the built in `WebDriverWait` function of selenium. This will accept as an argument a maximum time to wait for an element to load, and will return that element as soon as it's found. Something like:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.refresh()
my_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Workspace")))
# code that needs this element loaded
```

This will make the code freeze for up to 30 seconds, but it can continue sooner if the element loads sooner. If the element is not found after 30 seconds an exception is thrown.

You can read more about selenium waits [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: I have a couple of cuestions: First, when I typed the last line of code give error in the "undefined name self"...I executed without this part, is that affect?. Second, in 'code that need this element loaded' I only use sleep and refresh. ¿Is that correct?

Comment: @ChachoFuva My apologies, I copied that line from my project where the driver is an attribute of an object. `self.driver` should just be `driver` in your case. The point of this code is to avoid having to refresh many times. You should be able to call `.refresh()` once, and then this code will wait 30 seconds for that element to load. I don't really see a reason you would need to refresh the page many times (maybe I don't understand the problem completely). I would recommend you read through the selenium waits page that I linked to learn more about the various options.

Comment: I used only `driver.refresh()` after `my_element` line but the next element can't be located

Comment: @ChachoFuva Again, I would recommend you read the selenium wait documentation. There are many options for waits such as implicit, and explicit. Additionally there is functionality for you to implement your own wait, should you so choose.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it, with try and except.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to wait until a particular item is loaded, use Explicit Wait.
Below is JAVA solution example.

```
WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Workspace")));
```

Official Documentation: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/